# RoR Apple M2 trouble with bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, apple-m1

I recently switch to new machine that uses M2 chip and decided to create a new project on Rails. But every time I try to run "bundle install" command - it gives me out this kind of error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/a1111/RubymineProjects/FasterThanLightTest/FasterThanLightTest/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/racc-1.6.2/ext/racc/cparse
/Users/a1111/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby -I /Users/a1111/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20230227-63071-piv0lx.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_block_call()... no
checking for rb_ary_subseq()... no
creating Makefile
```

And then this one:

```
An error occurred while installing racc (1.6.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install racc -v '1.6.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 7.0.4.2, which depends on
    actioncable was resolved to 7.0.4.2, which depends on
      actionpack was resolved to 7.0.4.2, which depends on
        actionview was resolved to 7.0.4.2, which depends on
          rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
            nokogiri was resolved to 1.14.2, which depends on
              racc
```

What may be the problem? I've got latest Xcode command tool. My ruby version 3.0.0 and rails version is 7.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Find out that the problem was with different arch versions. For some reason I wasn't being able to install many gems under arch i386. But if I'll use for example "arch -arm64 gem install byebug" - it will go fine.